# Python: Multithreading using join and Queue sometimes blocks forever

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

My code is as follows:

```
def PreDutyCycleSolve(self, procCount):
    z = self.crystal.z

    #D1 = np.empty(len(z))
    #D2 = np.empty(len(z))

    D1D2q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    procs = []
    for proc in range(procCount):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.DutyCycleSolve,
                                    args=(proc,
                                          z[proc::procCount],
                                          D1D2q))
        procs.append(p)

    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

    while D1D2q.empty() is False:
        x = D1D2q.get()
        print x
```

I have a function, `DutyCycleSolve`, which get divided up and run from (in my case, four processes).  The issue is, depending on the length of the array, z, sometimes, the code just gets stuck and never proceeds past `proc.join`.  I've verified (by printing some text in `self.DutyCycleSolve` that `self.DutyCycleSolve` always returns and the process always exits from that function.

It appears that it exits from the function, and then (sometimes) gets stuck at `join`.

Any ideas why?  I'm new to this.

Thanks.

Comment: The program exists without the expected result or does it just get stuck at the `proc.join()` ?

Comment: Just gets stuck at join()

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming):

> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait
>   before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the
>   “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. [...]
>
> **This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that** 
>   **all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed** 
>   **before the process is joined**. Otherwise you cannot be sure that
>   processes which have put items on the queue will terminate. Remember
>   also that non-daemonic processes will be automatically be joined.

In other words, whenever you use queues, the right way to go is `get()` first, and then `join()`. See the docs for an example.